# Can't get basic Apache Axis webservice to work

Tags: java, linux, axis

My example works when run on my PC but not on a remote server.

I'm following the Apache Axis "User's Guide", which can be found on the axis.apache website. I'm trying to get the example "Basics - Getting Started" working using a web service hosted on a server I control.

My client side code is exaclty the same as the example in the document.

My server side code is this :

```
public class Test {
  public String echo(String s){
    return s;
  }
}
```

That code is in the File "apache-tomcat-7.0.81/webapps/axis/Test.jws". The "axis" directory is a copy of the one found in the axis download under webapps.

This actually does work when I run in on the Tomcat instance on my windows PC. I get the expected output when I run the client code:

```
Sent 'Hello!', got 'Hello!'
```

My problem happens when I try this on a remote server running centos7. I use the same code and the same axis webapp, but get this error in catalina.out:

```
- Exception:
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /usr/share/tomcat/webapps/axis/WEB-INF/jwsClasses/Test.java (No such file or directory)
```

On my local machine the file was created automatically, but on the Centos7 machine no file or directory is created. Any ideas what is going on here?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the tomcat user didn't have permission to create the jwsClasses/Test.java file.

Fixed with:

```
chown -R tomcat:tomcat /usr/share/tomcat/webapps/axis
```